# BackgroundUploader Sample does not work on Apache Server with PHP

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have to upload a video file from an windows phone 8.1 app.
I am using the [BackgroundTrasfer sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/) but for the server side there is just a aspx script. But I need PHP.

I have found this PHP script

```
<?php  
    $target = "upload/";  
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']) ;  
    $ok=1;  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target))  { 
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
    }  else { 
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    } 
?>
```

Finally I get a 200 and no errors but there is no file on the server so I would say the server part is the problem?
Where I can get a working server part script?

P.S. The directory "upload" exist in the same directory like the upload.php and has the rights 777.

Comment: Where is the `upload` directory located? Are you looking in the right places?

Comment: the uri for the uploader is http://www.server.com/upload_test/upload.php the directory http://www.server.com/upload_test/upload/ exist an has the rights 777

Comment: Not the URI for the php file, I meant the actual path on the disk.

Comment: the directory "upload" is in the same directory like the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a  `multipart/form-data` request.

Try something like (pseudo code):

```
List<BackgroundTransferContentPart> parts =
    new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();
var part = new BackgroundTransferContentPart("myFile");
part.SetFile(file);
parts.Add(part);

UploadOperation upload = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(
    uri,
    parts);

var task = upload.StartAsycn().AsTask();
```

On PHP, explore the recevied files with `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps a bit. Now I can say the server part (PHP) is fine. The client part have to be changed due to multipart/form-data.

Comment: If you are printing anything from your PHP script and you want to see the response from the client, you should take a look at: https://monkeyweekend.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-get-the-response-content-of-a-background-transfer-downloadoperation-when-the-result-is-not-200-ok/